# When to use one queue vs multiple?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, message-queue, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Say I want to send emails to users.

- When users sign up for an account they get an email.
- When they complete an order they get an email.
- When they receive a message they get an email.

My hunch is that a event Fanout is a good approach to use here. Say I have multiple SNS topics e.g. `orders`, `users`, `messages`. Each topic has their respective events e.g. `order_created`, `user_created`, `message_created`.

My question is which one to choose:

1. Create a single queue that subscribes to all of these topics with an attached worker that will send the appropriate email based on the event
2. Create a separate queue for each of these topics where the attached worker only sends a specific email

I am having a hard time identifying obvious pros / cons. Also more generally what are scenarios where you would have one queue subscribe to multiple topics vs multiple queues each subscribed to a single topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my pros and cons for the two options that you have listed.

### Single queue for multiple topics

#### Pros

- Less components that needs to be monitored
- Better resource utilization if the individual topics have not too many messages

#### Cons

- If one topic can have a lot more messages than others then it can cause delay for other topics' messages
- It is easier to reach the max messages / queue quota with a single queue
- If the queue becomes temporarily unreachable then none of the message types processing can advance

### Dedicated queue per topic

#### Pros

- One queue could be setup as FIFO while others as standard

  - Different settings can be used for each queue (like: retention period, maximum message size, etc.)
- Easier to introduce different workers for different queues if the increased load requires that

  - Also you can scale up and down different workers based on the different queues' length

#### Cons

- If you introduce more and more message types then the number of topics, queues and workers can impose some maintenance burden on you
- It is harder to correlate two messages from different topics